# QML Scroll area with Column stacking items on top of eachother

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ScrollArea that contains a column of components but the column is stacking the items ontop of eachother when they are non-trivial.

This works exactly as expected:

```
ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column {

            Text { text: "hello world1" }
            Text { text: "hello world2" }
            Text { text: "hello world3" }
        }
    }
```

But this fails and just stacks all the items on top of eachother:

```
ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column {

            Rectangle {
                Column {
                    Text { text: "hello world1" }
                    Text { text: "hello world2" }
                    Text { text: "hello world3" }
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                Column {
                    Text { text: "hello world1" }
                    Text { text: "hello world2" }
                    Text { text: "hello world3" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried using ColumnLayout along with the Layout.fillHeight property for each rectangle but that doesn't seem to work. I guess this is being caused by the nested Columns since without nesting layout items organising components works fine.

Comment: This is because `Rectangle` does not take over the `implicitHeight` and `implicitWidth` of it's children

Comment: Ah I see. Is there a standard container type that does take the implicit height and width of its children so layouts work as expected?

Comment: The `Column` sets it implicit width/height (as quite some other types), but the question is why you want to have it wrapped?